# Ctrl + Space crashing ADT Bundle

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-adt

Why ctrl+space forcefully crashing the adt bundle in linux 14.04 ? When I am opening the eclipse its working fine and I'm able to do anything but when I'm pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> then its crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your eclipse.ini file (In your eclipse directory) and edit last three line as

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

close eclipse and restart system. It will work